# Macro IE controlling

Tags: excel, vba, anchor, temp

Unfortunately my parents are not familiar with using the computer at all, and I have moved to another city, so I cannot help them directly. They need to log in every month to their telephone service provider, and print out the due invoice. I'm trying to make a macro to execute all this with "only a click of a button".

So my code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 1027
objIE.Height = 768
objIE.AddressBar = 0
objIE.StatusBar = 0
objIE.Toolbar = 0
objIE.Visible = True

objIE.Navigate ("https://login.example.com")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

    SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'security pop up, press enter

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

'write in login name and password

    objIE.document.GetElementByID("f_name_1").Value = "abababa"
    objIE.document.GetElementByID("password").Value = "cdc999"

'press enter, log in

    SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

'and here I stuck

End Sub
```

But at one point I got stuck. Unfortunately on the website when you log in, the navigation button's code looks something like this:

```
<a class="cufon_w" id="tempID" href="fakt.do">
```

I tried with:

```
objIE.document.GetElementByID("tempID").Click
```

and:

```
objIE.document.GetElementByClassName("cufon_w").Click
```

but it does not work with either of them (with tempID I was supposing, but tried it anyway).

Has anybody tried something similar, or know any solution?

Comment: What happened when you tried: `objIE.document.GetElementByID("tempID").Click` ?  That should work.

Comment: You may want to try avoiding late binding.  I've seen the more generic "document.GetElementByID("")" return some odd objects before.  You may want to add references to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library and rely on VBA to pick types for you a little less.  I can't promise that will fix it though, but it might give you more useful information.

Comment: [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) may allow you to help them directly.